# How do I make this DWORD value entry in regedit using batch file?

Tags: batch, regedit

How do I create this DWORD value using a batch file?

Key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\

Value: `mybrowser.exe`
Data: `11001` (binary)
Type: `REG_DWORD`

It should look like:
[image]

I tried:

> Reg Add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\" /V "system" /D 0 /T REG_DWORD /F 0x2AF9

But it's not working. Any advice?

Comment: What about it isn't working? Is the cmd not executing, or is it executing incorrectly? What are the results?

Comment: cmd executing incorrectly, the batch is like executing non stop !! and no value entry is made :(

Comment: @user3740292 Just a guess: [`reg add command will NOT create the entire directory path if it does not exist`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809856/run-reg-command-in-cmd-bat-file)